# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) when retrieving a file in Win 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to retrieve a file data using C# code

```
StorageFile pFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filepath);
```

I am getting `E_ACCESSDENIED` if my path is other than the `AppData` of my Project.
I am working on Visual studio 2012 for Windows 8. Even though files have read/write access and admin rights access, still getting same error.

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: That's entirely normal, your app runs in a sandbox that enforces the capabilities you requested in your app manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Your app runs in a sandbox. The only location you can access are the app installation path, localappdata and if you have activated the libraries.

Read this msdn article to get all possible file location:
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

> In addition to the default locations, a Windows Store app can access more files and folders by declaring capabilities in the app manifest (see App capability declarations), or by calling a file picker to let the user pick files and folders for the app to access (see Quickstart: Accessing files with file pickers).